# NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined

Tags: python, numpy, nameerror

I am working on machine learning using "Python Deep Learning" by coding the examples to get a better understanding.  I am trying to execute the code at the end of Ch. 3. Executing the code gives me a `NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined.`

The `import numpy` line was not part of the original text from the book, so I added that line after I received the same error before adding the line.  Initially, I supposed that one of the prior imports would have brought in numpy, but apparently I was incorrect.   Anyway, isn't the  line supposed to handle that error?

```py
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy

(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.reshape(60000, 784)
X_test = X_test.reshape(10000, 784)
classes = 100
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train, classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_test, classes)
input_size = 784
batch_size = 100
hidden_neurons = 100
epochs = 15
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(hidden_neurons, input_dim=input_size))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(classes, input_dim=hidden_neurons))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'],
              optimizer='sgd')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=epochs, verbose=1)
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=1)
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()
w = weights[0].T
for neuron in range(hidden_neurons):
    plt.imshow(numpy.reshape(w[neuron], (28, 28)), cmap = cm.Greys_r)
    plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyPython.py", line 31, in <module>
    plt.imshow(numpy.reshape(w[neuron], (28, 28)),
NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined
```

I don't understand why and I don;t have an expected result for the plot (yet).  I need to make the code work so I can start exploring the internals to get a better understanding about what is going on, because this is my first introduction to keras.

Comment: Post something we can actually run, that reproduces the error when run. It doesn't have to be the full program that prompted you to ask this question - it can be substantially stripped down or even rewritten from scratch - but it has to be something we can run and reproduce the error with.

Comment: Here is a link demonstrating what @user2357112 and all of us want from you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The instructions below the code block suggest not to provide the entire code, so I didn't.  When I try to edit the code to provide the program, the editor complains about improper indentation and doing Ctrl-K to the 2 indented lines does not fix it and it complains about other lines that are not indented.  So, without providing the complete code, you cannot execute it and the editor is not allowing me to provide complete code!!!

Answer (score 1):

Above provided code does not show any kind of error for me and at least runs fine. Are you sure you have Numpy installed? you will know it (if working with Anaconda) by typing in terminal

```
conda list
```

If it does not show numpy, you can install it by following command

```
conda install numpy
```

Or you can try

```
pip install numpy
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes numpy is installed:

Comment: I have not changed any single thing in the code you provided, it works for me. Are you working with Anaconda environment?

Comment: numpy                     1.15.2           py35h6a91979_0  
numpy-base             1.15.2           py35h8a80b8c_0    
And, yes, I'm working in Anaconda, However I am using the Atom editor and Terminal to execute the code.  Also, I'm using Python 3.5.3 as my python3 package.  So, now i am baffled, i.e. why doesn't work for me ???

Comment: So the first thing comes into my mind is you might not be running the python for which Numpy is installed, make sure you are using the same python for which Numpy is installed.

Comment: Bizarre, it doesn't work in Atom and Terminal, but it does work in Anaconda Spyder. Curious !!!  I found numby when I typed <conda list> in Terminal.  When I run python3 it shows:  Python 3.5.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit).

Comment: I mean, are you able to import Numpy in python3 ? If not then for sure you have different python versions and one of them numpy is not installed

Comment: Yes, I understand that others run it with no problems.  I don't need ant more feedback.  I will be checking my python3 system to try to isolate the internal problem.  Thanks for all of your help.